# Right turn lights don't blink

Tags: chevrolet, lights, lumina

I'm stumped - All left turn lights blink on-off (you do have to jiggle the column lever though); no jiggling required for right turn, but, all right turn lights stay on and don't blink. All bulbs are good and all blink for emergency flasher. 1991 Chev Lumina Euro
I'm open to any ideas of what's going on . . .

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I'm deleting my answer, because I realize it is completely wrong. Not sure what I was thinking, because GM vehicles *blink faster* when a bulb goes out. My only other thought would be that the switch has gone bad (switch in the steering column).

Comment: I had this issue with a bad battery.